# SqlMetal wrongly generates the return type of my stored proc (LINQ)

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures, sqlmetal

Hi have a stored proc that always returns a single row depending of a parameter:

```
IF @bleh = 1
  SELECT TOP 1 Xyz FROM Abc
ELSE
  SELECT TOP 1 Def FROM Abc
```

I must use SqlMetal to generate the DataContext but this stored procedure returns a `IMultipleResults`, which is an error. Instead it should return a `ISingleResult`...

If I remove the if (putting a single `SELECT` call), an `ISingleResult` return type is generated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version are you using?  I tried to reproduce this with VS 2010 Beta 2 but it worked as expected.  Am assuming you're using VS 2008 SP 1?

Comment: Can you add the table definition, I doubt it has anything to do with the issue, but you never know..  Also, is there anything else in the Proc besides the IF and the two select statements?

Comment: Yes, using VS 2008 SP 1. There's nothing besides the `IF`. I'll try to add the table definition as soon as I get home. Thanks. I'll also try putting a return in each `IF/ELSE` conditions..

Comment: I'm sorry it will go to tomorrow, huge rush :S

Comment: @Rob were you using SqlMetal or the designer when testing VS2010 Beta 2? I still got IMultipleResults using SqlMetal. Please see my response below for details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The scenario you're describing is by design. I've tested with both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 Beta 2 and got the same results. Given a SPROC using an IF/ELSE structure as yours does, the generated results and tools used are:

- **SqlMetal**: *IMultipleResults*
- **LINQ To SQL Designer** (drag & drop in the VS IDE): *ISingleResult*

This is [supported by Matt Warren](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/ce90169d-70e7-41e7-9828-aca0eceab769/) at Microsoft:

> The designer does not recognize stored
>   procs with multiple return values and
>   will map them all to returning a
>   single integer.
>
> SQLMetal command line tool does
>   recognize the multiple results and
>   will type the return of the method
>   correctly as IMultipleResults.  You
>   can either use SQLMetal or modify the
>   DBML by hand or add the method
>   signature for this stored proc to your
>   own partial class for your
>   DataContext.

In [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2008/05/16/linq-to-sql-tips-7.aspx) Dinesh Kulkarni comments on the opposite scenario where the designer doesn't add IMultipleResults and uses ISingleResult instead. He states (emphasis added):

> And no, the designer does not support
>   this feature. So you have to add the
>   method in your partial class. SqlMetal
>   does however extract the sproc. **The
>   reason for that is an implementation
>   detail: the two use the same code
>   generator but different database
>   schema extractors.**

In addition, the section titled "Handling Multiple Result Shapes from SPROCs" in [Scott Gu's post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx) and [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399371.aspx) both show IMultipleResults being used with SPROCs that use the same structure.

Great, now what? There are a few workarounds, some are nicer than others.

---

#### Rewrite the SPROC

You can rewrite the SPROC so that SqlMetal generates the function using ISingleResult. This can be achieved by

**Rewrite #1 - Storing the result in a variable:**

```
DECLARE @Result INT
IF @Input = 1
    SET @Result = (SELECT TOP 1 OrderId FROM OrderDetails)
ELSE
    SET @Result = (SELECT TOP 1 ProductId FROM OrderDetails ORDER BY ProductId DESC)

SELECT @Result As Result
```

Obviously the types will need to be similar or something that can be cast to the other. For example, if one was an `INT` and the other was a `DECIMAL(8, 2)` you would use the decimal to retain precision.

**Rewrite #2 - Use a case statement:**

This is identical to [Mark's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037280/sqlmetal-wrongly-generates-the-return-type-of-my-stored-proc-linq/2150955#2150955).

```
SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN @Input = 1 THEN OrderId ELSE ProductId END FROM OrderDetails
```

---

#### Use a UDF instead of a SPROC

You could use a [scalar-valued UDF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386973.aspx) and adjust your query to use the UDF format (identical to the variable approach mentioned above). SqlMetal will generate an ISingleResult for it since only one value is returned.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnODIds] 
(
    @Input INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result INT

    IF @Input = 1
        SET @Result = (SELECT TOP 1 UnitPrice FROM OrderDetails)
    ELSE
        SET @Result = (SELECT TOP 1 Quantity FROM OrderDetails ORDER BY Quantity DESC)

    RETURN @Result

END
```

---

#### Fake the SPROC & switch it out

This works but is more tedious than the previous options. Also, future use of SqlMetal would overwrite these changes and require the process to be repeated. Using a partial class and moving the relative code there would help prevent this.

*1)* Change your SPROC to return a single `SELECT` statement (comment out your actual code), such as `SELECT TOP 1 OrderId FROM OrderDetails`

*2)* Use SqlMetal. It will generate an ISingleResult:

```
[Function(Name = "dbo.FakeODIds")]
public ISingleResult<FakeODIdsResult> FakeODIds([Parameter(Name = "Input", DbType = "Int")] System.Nullable<int> input)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), input);
    return ((ISingleResult<FakeODIdsResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

*3)* Change your SPROC back to its original form but use the same alias for the returned result. For example, I will return *both* `OrderId` and `ProductId` as `FakeId`.

```
IF @Input = 1
    SELECT TOP 1 OrderId As FakeId FROM OrderDetails
ELSE
    SELECT TOP 1 Quantity As FakeId FROM OrderDetails ORDER BY Quantity DESC
```

Notice I am not using a variable here but using the format you originally started with directly.

*4)* Since we're using the FakeId alias we need to tweak the generated code. If you navigate to the mapped class that was generated for you in step 2 (`FakeODIdsResult` in my case). The class will be using the original column name from step 1 in the code, `OrderId` in my case. In fact, this whole step could be avoided if the statement in step 1 was aliased to start with, ie. `SELECT TOP 1 OrderId As FakeId FROM OrderDetails`. If you didn't though, you need to go in and tweak things.

FakeODIdsResult will be using `OrderId`, which will return nothing since it aliases `FakeId`. It will look similar to this:

```
public partial class FakeODIdsResult
{
    private System.Nullable<int> _OrderId;

    public FakeODIdsResult()
    {
    }

    [Column(Storage = "_OrderId", DbType = "Int")]
    public System.Nullable<int> OrderId
    {
        get
        {
            return this._OrderId;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._OrderId != value))
            {
                this._OrderId = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What you need to do is rename `OrderId` to `FakeId` and `_OrderId` to `_FakeId`. Once that's done, you can use the ISingleResult above as you normally would, for example:

```
int fakeId = dc.FakeODIds(i).Single().FakeId;
```

---

This concludes what I've used and was able to find on the topic.

Comment: +1 well done!  I didn't have VS 2008 installed, and I didn't want to 'muddy' my investigation by using VS 2010 Beta 2 just in case it was something that had been addressed (or not), glad you got to the bottom of it